# Unable to provide implicit conversion from DateTime to Ordered using implicit conversion to Comparable

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use >=,>, etc. with DateTime (joda), and the only way I could get it to work was using this implicit conversion

```
implicit def dateTime2ordered(x: DateTime): Ordered[DateTime] =
new Ordered[DateTime] with Proxy {
  val self = x

  def compare(y: DateTime): Int = {
    x.compareTo(y)
  }
}
```

I would have preferred a more generic form such as

```
implicit def comparable2ordered[A <: Comparable[A]](x: A): Ordered[A] =
    new Ordered[A] with Proxy {
      val self = x

      def compare(y: A): Int = {
        x.compareTo(y)
      }
    }
```

But the compiler can't find this conversion, and after trying to invoke it directly, I've gotten the following message claiming that DateTime is not of type Comparable[A]. After checking the source for DateTime, I saw that it only implements Comparable as a raw type.

I was able to get it work using

```
 implicit def comparable2ordered[A <: Comparable[_]](x: A): Ordered[A] =
    new Ordered[A] with Proxy {
      val self = x

      def compare(y: A): Int = {
        x.compareTo(y)
      }
    }
```

My question is: Is this the correct Scala treatment of this problem, or would the wildcard type bound cause future problems with type checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is fine, a raw type "Comparable" gets translated to "Comparable[_]" in Scala.

They're called Existential Types, Comparable[_] is a shorthand for  " Comparable[T] forSome { type T } " (since version 2.7 see http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43 )

See also "Existential types" in http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scalas_type_system.html

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled across this question because I, too, was looking to compare joda DateTime objects using relational operators.

Daniel's answer pointed me in the right direction: the implicits present in `scala.math.Ordered` will convert an instance of `A extends java.lang.Comparable[A]` to an `Ordered[A]` - they just need to be brought into scope. The easiest way to do this (which I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483405/idiomatic-use-of-a-java-comparable-object), btw) is with the `implicitly` method:

```
val aOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[A]]
import aOrdering._
```

The catch is that `org.joda.time.DateTime` doesn't extend or implement `Comparable` itself, it inherits (indirectly) from `org.joda.time.ReadableInstant`, which *does* extends `Comparable`. So this:

```
val dateTimeOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[DateTime]]
import dateTimeOrdering._
```

won't compile, because the `DateTime` doesn't extend `Comparable[DateTime]`. To use `Ordered`'s relational operators on a `DateTime`, you have to do this instead:

```
val instantOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[ReadableInstant]]
import instantOrdering._
```

which works because `ReadableInstant` extends `Comparable[ReadableInstant]`, and the implicit conversions in `Ordered` can convert it to an `Ordered[ReadableInstant]`.

So far, so good. However, there are situations where an `Ordered[ReadableInstant]` isn't good enough. (The one I encountered is with ScalaTest's [greater and less than Matchers](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#greaterAndLessThan).) To get an `Ordered[DateTime]`, I was forced to do this:

```
implicit object DateTimeOrdering extends Ordering[DateTime] {
  def compare(d1: DateTime, d2: DateTime) = d1.compareTo(d2)
}
```

It seems like there ought to be an easier way, but I couldn't figure one out.

Comment: I think this works: `import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._`

Comment: Yeah, that works, but only if you're using the nscala-time library. ;)

Comment: I like the "extends Ordering" solution: short and clean and keeps the "magic" to a minimum

Answer (score 2):

See, the thing is, this already exists. Well, kind of... If you look inside object `Ordered`, where implicit conversions are looked for, you'll find this:

```
implicit def orderingToOrdered [T] (x: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) : Ordered[T]
```

So, as long as there's an `Ordering[T]` available, one can produce an `Ordered[T]`. Now, to look for an `Ordering[T]` inside the `Ordering` object:

```
implicit def ordered [A] (implicit arg0: (A) ⇒ Comparable[A]) : Ordering[A]
```

So, if you pass a `comparable: A with Comparable[A]` to something expecting an `Ordered[A]`, it will do this:

```
Ordered.orderingToOrdered(comparable)(Ordering.ordered(Predef.identity(comparable)))
```

Now, as to your question: using existential types is the correct way of handling Java raw types. It is theoretically possible for this to result in an incorrect ordering, but, in practice, extremely unlikely. You *may* have problems with implicit ambiguity, though, since Scala already have a `Comparable => Ordered` implicit conversion, as seen above.