# Idiomatic use of a Java comparable object

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I'm using some java.util.Date (which implements java.lang.Comparable) and would like to be able to use it nicely, e.g. use < and >= instead of "compareTo(other) == 1". Is there a nice way to just easily mix in something like scala.math.Ordered without a lot of boiler plate?

Comment: you could do an implicit from date to ordered, are you looking for something else ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Ordering companion object there is an implicit conversion from Comparable[A] to Ordering[A]. So you can do this:

```
import java.util.Date

val dateOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[Date]]
import dateOrdering._

val now = new Date
val then = new Date(now.getTime + 1000L)

println(now < then) // true
```

Comment: A slight caveat: If you have a class `B` that inherits from `A implements Comparable<A>` (Java syntax), you can't get `implicitly[Ordering[B]]`. You have to use `implicitly[Ordering[A]]` instead.

Comment: Very nice. Hopefully Scala 2.12 makes this work by default / easier - also for `Instant` etc.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but here's a slightly simpler solution that may not have been available when the question was asked.

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
```

Any Java types that implement `Comparable` should then work seamlessly with comparison operators. For example,

```
import java.time.Instant

val x = Instant.now()
val y = x.plusSeconds(1)

print(x < y)   // prints true
print(x <= y)  // prints true
print(x > y)   // prints false
```

Comment: Nice answer but sadly this only works for infix operators. `x max y` works but looks pretty strange.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix in `Ordered` in this case, afaik... I tried it and ran into difficulties because `compareTo` is defined both there and in `java.lang.Comparable`. The compiler complains that `Ordered` doesn't use `override` in its definition of the method; I don't know how to get around that.

So define an implicit `Ordering[Date]`. You can put this `DateOrdering` object anywhere (e.g. in companion object).

```
import java.util.Date
implicit object DateOrdering extends Ordering[Date] {
  def compare(x: Date, y: Date) = x compareTo y
}
```

Then in your code:

```
import DateOrdering._
val a = new Date
Thread.sleep(1000)
val b = new Date
println(a < b)     // prints true
println(a >= b)    // prints false
```

The `Ordering` object contains an `implicit def mkOrderingOps (lhs: T): Ops`. The `Ops` class contains the `<`. `>=` etc methods, and this implicit def is an example of the *[pimp my library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766)* pattern on whatever the type parameter of the Ordering is (here, any `Date` instance).